# GroupBY with alaSQL in an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, alasql

I need help to achieve this transformation of an Array of Objects.
I am working with alaSQL.
I need to do a GroupBY by player.
I tried
`alasql('SELECT score FROM ? WHERE score GROUP BY player',[arrayGamePlayerObjects])`
But I got this result

```
{
  "player": {
    "id": 5,
    "firstName": "Player",
    "lastName": "05",
    "email": "player05@example.com"
  }
}
```

Original Array of Objects:

```
[
    {
    "player": {"id": 5,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "05","email": "player05@example.com"},
    "score": {"id": 5,"score": 0.5,"finishDate": "2022-05-05T16:12:22.038+00:00",
            "game":   {"id": 3,"gameName": "Game 03","gameDate": "2022-05-05T18:12:21.049+00:00"},
            "player": {"id": 5,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "05","email": "player05@example.com"}
            }
    },
    {
    "player": {"id": 6,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "06","email": "player06@example.com"},
    "score": {"id": 6,"score": 0.5,"finishDate": "2022-05-05T16:12:22.038+00:00",
            "game": {"id": 3,"gameName": "Game 03","gameDate": "2022-05-05T18:12:21.049+00:00"},
            "player": {"id": 6,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "06","email": "player06@example.com"}
            }
    },
    {
    "player": {"id": 5,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "05","email": "player05@example.com"},
    "score": {"id": 7,"score": 0.5,"finishDate": "2022-05-05T16:12:22.042+00:00",
            "game": {"id": 6,"gameName": "Game 06","gameDate": "2022-05-05T20:12:21.049+00:00"},
            "player": {"id": 5,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "05","email": "player05@example.com"}
            }
    },
    {
    "player": {"id": 6,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "06","email": "player06@example.com"},
    "score": {"id": 8,"score": 0.5,"finishDate": "2022-05-05T16:12:22.042+00:00",
            "game": {"id": 6,"gameName": "Game 06","gameDate": "2022-05-05T20:12:21.049+00:00"},
            "player": {"id": 6,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "06","email": "player06@example.com"}
            }
    }
```

The end result I need is :

```
[
    {
    "player": {"id": 5,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "05","email": "player05@example.com"},
            "score01": {"id": 5,"score": 0.5,"finishDate": "2022-05-05T16:12:22.038+00:00",
                    "game":   {"id": 3,"gameName": "Game 03","gameDate": "2022-05-05T18:12:21.049+00:00"},
                    "player": {"id": 5,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "05","email": "player05@example.com"}
            },
            "score02": {"id": 7,"score": 0.5,"finishDate": "2022-05-05T16:12:22.042+00:00",
                    "game": {"id": 6,"gameName": "Game 06","gameDate": "2022-05-05T20:12:21.049+00:00"},
                    "player": {"id": 5,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "05","email": "player05@example.com"}
            }
    },
    {
    "player": {"id": 6,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "06","email": "player06@example.com"},
            "score01": {"id": 6,"score": 0.5,"finishDate": "2022-05-05T16:12:22.038+00:00",
                    "game": {"id": 3,"gameName": "Game 03","gameDate": "2022-05-05T18:12:21.049+00:00"},
                    "player": {"id": 6,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "06","email": "player06@example.com"}
                    },
            "score02": {"id": 8,"score": 0.5,"finishDate": "2022-05-05T16:12:22.042+00:00",
                    "game": {"id": 6,"gameName": "Game 06","gameDate": "2022-05-05T20:12:21.049+00:00"},
                    "player": {"id": 6,"firstName": "Player","lastName": "06","email": "player06@example.com"}
                    }
    }
]
```

Any guide or ideas on how to get this result ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help!

### Implementation

```js
const groupBy = key => array =>
  array.reduce((objectsByKeyValue, obj) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    objectsByKeyValue[value] = (objectsByKeyValue[value] || []).concat(obj);
    return objectsByKeyValue;
  }, {});
```

### Usage

```js
const cars = [
  { brand: 'Audi', color: 'black' },
  { brand: 'Audi', color: 'white' },
  { brand: 'Ferarri', color: 'red' },
  { brand: 'Ford', color: 'white' },
  { brand: 'Peugot', color: 'white' }
];

const groupByBrand = groupBy('brand');
const groupByColor = groupBy('color');

console.log(
  JSON.stringify({
    carsByBrand: groupByBrand(cars),
    carsByColor: groupByColor(cars)
  }, null, 2)
);
```

#### Output

```json
{
  "carsByBrand": {
    "Audi": [
      {
        "brand": "Audi",
        "color": "black"
      },
      {
        "brand": "Audi",
        "color": "white"
      }
    ],
    "Ferarri": [
      {
        "brand": "Ferarri",
        "color": "red"
      }
    ],
    "Ford": [
      {
        "brand": "Ford",
        "color": "white"
      }
    ],
    "Peugot": [
      {
        "brand": "Peugot",
        "color": "white"
      }
    ]
  },
  "carsByColor": {
    "black": [
      {
        "brand": "Audi",
        "color": "black"
      }
    ],
    "white": [
      {
        "brand": "Audi",
        "color": "white"
      },
      {
        "brand": "Ford",
        "color": "white"
      },
      {
        "brand": "Peugot",
        "color": "white"
      }
    ],
    "red": [
      {
        "brand": "Ferarri",
        "color": "red"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ref: [from](https://gist.github.com/JamieMason/0566f8412af9fe6a1d470aa1e089a752#file-group-objects-by-property-md)

Comment: I am exploring this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706735/group-map-points-by-their-category-in-javascript/27619062#27619062 . When I have the specific answer for my question I will post the solution .

Answer (score 0):

I used alaSQL with this query and works Ok .

```
alasql('SELECT player->id , ARRAY(_) AS gamePlayer_per_player FROM ? WHERE score GROUP BY player->id',[arrayGamePlayerObjects]);
```

Comment: By the way the statement `alasql('SELECT player->id as playerid , ARRAY(_) AS gamePlayer_per_player FROM ? WHERE score GROUP BY playerid',[arrayGamePlayerObjects]);` didnt work for for me . For some reason the `player->id as playerid` gave undefined